# Number of partitions needed in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, partitioning

In Spark summit 2013 one of the yahoo presentation had this [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gOze.png) mentioned:

> partitions needed = total data size/(memory size/number of cores)

Assuming a 64Gb memory host with 16 cores of CPU.

The presentation mentioned that to process 3Tb of data, the number of partitions needed is 46080. I am having hard time getting to the same result. Please explain the calculation, how the number 46080 came?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the presentation (available [here](https://spark-summit.org/2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Li-AEX-Spark-yahoo.pdf)), the information available is:

- 64Gb memory host
- 16 core cpu
- Compression rato 30:1, 2 times overhead

Your formula should use the uncompressed data size when calculating, therefore, in this case you need to first uncompress it.

Data size = 3Tb * 30 * 2 = 180Tb = 184320Gb

Running it through the formula you get:
184320Gb/(64Gb/16) = 46080 partitions